# Bash script login to ssh and run some commands

Tags: git, bash, ssh, travis-ci

After travis completes and is successful I am trying to run a bash script which I am pretty new to.

I basically want it to login to a remote server and got a pull from the master branch on git and then restart the node.js server

```
spawn ssh couch@********* -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect "assword:"
send "*******\r"
cd localer
forever stop server.js
git pull origin master
forever start server.js
exit
```

This is what I have so far but it gives me an error on travis-ci

```
./deploy.sh: line 1: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "assword:": no such file or directory
./deploy.sh: line 3: send: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 4: cd: localer: No such file or directory
./deploy.sh: line 5: forever: command not found
From git://github.com/*******
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
./deploy.sh: line 7: forever: command not found
```

I installed expect in the travis environment but it says send and spawn are not known packages so I assume they are just bash properties.

Hope you can help :)

Comment: That's a mix of shell and expect there. If you are trying to use expect you need to write an expect script (the lines up through `send`) and then send the commands (the lines from `cd` to the end) to the spawned process.

Comment: @EtanReisner something like this then? http://pastebin.com/0Usz0htV

Comment: You probably want to wait for the prompt before sending but yes something like that I think.

Comment: Got it working now thanks, will post answer below if your interested to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it like this in the end

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh couch@*************** -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect "assword:"
send "*******\r"
set prompt {\$ $}
expect -re $prompt
send "cd localer\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "forever stop server.js\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "git pull origin master\r"
sleep 10
expect -re $prompt
send "forever start server.js\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ssh keys ?

on your local machine, run `ssh-keygen`, after the process is done, get the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, log in in your remote server, past the content in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now logout and try to login again. You won't be prompted for a password again (which is much better to have it stored in plain in your script), and now you can use this syntax to run remote commands:

`ssh user@host "set -x; cd .; pwd; ls -lah; any command you want"`

Comment: The problem is with travis-ci the ssh key will be a different ssh key every time?

Comment: Hm... actually the direct command string can probably be used even in the original case. That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not a good idea to put plaintext passwords into text files.

Set up [SSH public/private keys](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html), then you can simply redirect a local script into ssh like so to run the script remotely:

ssh user@machine 'bash -s' < local_script.sh